# Programmatically grant android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY permission during android integration tests

Tags: android, notifications

Is there any way how to grant `android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` permission during Android tests?

Most of the permissions and even not runtime permission is easy to get in the test environment by calling

```
GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS,
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
)
```

But I need to test `NotificationListenerService` functionality, which needs to enable `Notification access`. And this doesn't work.